# Lost data when read from TFRecords

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow, reshape

I am working on creating tfrecords file and reading data from tfrecords. The tfrecords have two feature, vehicleid and length.

create tfrecords:

```
writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename + '_Squence.tfrecords')
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(
    feature={
        'vehicleid': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[vehicleid])),
        'length': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[length]))

    }))
writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()
```

read tfrecords:

```
filepath = filename + "_Squence.tfrecords"
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filepath])
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)   # return filename and file
features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features={
    'vehicleid': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'length': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    })

vehicleid = tf.cast(features["vehicleid"], tf.int64)
length = tf.cast(features["length"], tf.int64)
return vehicleid, length
```

But when I debug the code, I will lose some data. 
For example, if I send this two examples

[vehicleid=a, frameid=b], 
[vehicleid=c, frameid=d]

into tfrecords file, when I read the data, I will get data like this

[vehicleid =a, frameid=d].

I lost some data.

Would someone please help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.train.string_input_producer([filepath])` returns a queue. Every time you accees using the `reader.read(filename_queue)` it returns the last first element of the queue. If you execute `reader.read` for the second time it will return the second element.

If you want to reach a batch of element, you can use `tf.train.batch` with output of queue as input to `tf.train.batch.`